# Group with > 1 elements that is a free group and a permutation group?

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Consider the set $S = \{A, B\}$ and the group $G = \{e_G, \varphi\}$ with operation composition (where $e$ is the identity map and $\varphi$ maps $A$ to $B$ and $B$ to $A$). This is the permutation group on $S$ (that is, a group whose elements are the bijective mappings from $S$ to itself).

Given $\alpha$, a map from $S$ to $G$, why is it impossible for $G$ to be a free group? That is: If $\alpha'$ is a map from $S$ to some other group, $G'$, why is there **not** a unique homomorphism, $\mu$, from $G$ to $G'$ such that $\alpha' = \mu \circ \alpha$?

I'm asked to prove that the *only* group which can be both a free group and a permutation group is the group with a single element (the identity), but I am not convinced this is true. As far as I can tell, if we map the elements of $S$ to some $G'$, there's only one possibility when mapping elements of $G$ to $G'$, and said possibility would *have to* preserve composition within $G'$.

The first thing I think is: "Well, something in $S$ is necessarily mapped to $e_G$, and the only way $\mu$ can be a homomorphism is if $\mu(e_G) = e_{G'}$. Thus, the only way $G$ can be a free group is if something in $S$ mapped to $e_{G'}$ in the first place—which is not a constraint we can assume."

... but the group w/ only a single element has the identity as its element, so that assumption would be made anyway.

Comment: Suppose $S=G'$ are both the cyclic group of order $3$, and consider the identity map between the two copies.

Comment: The nonidentity element would have to be a generator if $G$ were a free group. That would mean there is a homomorphism from $G$ into any group that sends the nonidentity element to any element you want. But that's not true, because the element has order 2, so you couldn't send it to an element of order 3.

Comment: @lulu If $S = G'$ are both cyclic groups of order $3$, then the only element in $G$ is $\varphi$—which maps $s_1$ to $s_2$, $s_2$ to $s_3$, and $s_3$ to $s_1$, right? (Since $G$ is a permutation group, it's the group of bijective mappings from $S$ to $S$, which consists of just that one function.) How, then, could $G$ also be a free group? That is, if we consider the identity mapping between $S$ and $G'$, $\alpha: S \rightarrow G$ must be such that everything in $S$ maps to $\varphi$. How, then, can $\alpha' = \mu \circ \alpha$? That is, how do we "unpack" everything?

Comment: @AmagicalFishy  I was suggesting a counterexample.  There is no non-trivial map from the cyclic group of order $2$ to the cyclic group of order $3$, hence (using the notation of your post) there can be no homomorphism $\mu$ of the type you want.  Perhaps I misunderstood your question, but I thought that's the sort of example you were looking for.

Comment: @lulu I think, ultimately, I feel like the question should be: "Prove that the only set whose permutation group and free group are isomorphic is the set with but a single element." Also: This book defines a permutation group as a group whose elements are all bijective mappings from $S$ onto itself. Wikipedia, on the other hand, defines it as the group whose elements are permutations of elements of $S$. Aren't these two definitions different? In the example of $S = \{A, B\}$, the first definition would give $G = \{\varphi\}$ while the second definition would give $G = \{AB, BA\}$.

Comment: @AmagicalFishy  Not following.  Those two definitions appear equivalent to me (Well, I'd define a permutation as a bijection).  Indeed in your example, the map which exchanges $A,B$ is both a bijection and a permutation (under any definition).  Are your groups finite?  If so, then the counterexample I gave can be generalized to all $G$.  Infinite permutation groups...well, still not free but getting harder to work with.

Comment: @lulu First, thanks for sticking with me for this long. :) The group I'm thinking of is finite. In the above example (definitions between my textbook and Wikipedia), one fruits a group whose set has one element (that is, the function $\varphi$, and the other fruits a group whose set has two elements (the set $\{AB, BA\}$). So, in one case, the map, $\alpha$, from $S$ to $G$ can map an element of $S$ to *only* $\varphi$ ($\alpha(A) = \varphi$ **and** $\alpha(B) = \varphi$). In the other case, $\alpha$ can map an element of $S$ to *either* $AB$ or $BA$ (so $\alpha(A) = AB$ and $\alpha(B) = BA$).

Comment: @lulu I feel like I am missing something fundamental. I understand how $\varphi$ can cycle through all permutations, and in that way the set of permutations, and the set of bijective functions are "the same," but in any cyclic group, the function itself will just be one element of the set, while the set of all permutations will be $n!$ elements.

Comment: @AmagicalFishy  No, really.  Both definitions yield cyclic groups of order $2$.  A bijection is just a set theoretic function that is both injective and surjective.  The identity is a bijection, but so is the map that switches the two letters.  Easy to see that the latter has order $2$.  For finite sets, permutations mean exactly the same thing.  People argue over what "permutation" means for infinite sets, better to drop the issue until you are clear on finite examples.

Comment: @lulu Ok, here's where I think my misunderstanding may be: When one says "the set of bijective functions from a set to itself," this **includes** composition of the *same* function. So, with $S = \{A, B\}$, the set of bijective functions is $\{\varphi, \varphi \circ \varphi\}$, and not just $\varphi$, yes? (See, I know what a bijection is and all of these things. I am just confused by, apparently, a very basic premise—when one says "the set of all bijective functions from $S$ to itself," does it include composition of the *same* function?)

Comment: @AmagicalFishy  The set of all bijections is just that, the set of all bijections.  How you enumerate them is your look out.  In this case, there are obviously two functions:  the identity and the transposition.  Composition provides new structure, a way to multiply bijections.  So, the identity map becomes the identity element under this operation, and the transposition becomes an element of order $2$.

Answer (score 1):

The group is not free, since $\varphi^2=e_G$ and [free groups have no torsion.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2217216/104041)

Answer (score 1):

Free groups of order $\gt1$ are infinite.

If the group is finite, then let $g\neq e\in G$.  Then if $n=\mid G\mid$, we have $g^n=e$, which is a relation on $G$ other than that between an element and its inverse.  I.e. $G$ is not free.

On the other hand,  if the group is infinite, then it can be free and isomorphic to a permutation group (as, by [Cayley's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem) , every group is isomorphic to a permutation group).