# Prove every free group is torsion-free

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, group-presentation

> Prove every free group is torsion-free.

Here is my attempt:

Let $F$ be a free group and let $a \in F$ be an element of finite order, i.e. $a^n=1$ for some $n > 0$. Also $a=a_1...a_s$ is a reduced word of length $s>0$, i.e. $a$ is an non-identity element.

It suffices to show a contradiction. But I don't know exactly how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: given a word $a \not = e$ (not assumed to be torsion! we're proving this directly, not by contradiction), write it as $u w u^{-1}$ with no cancellation between $u$ and $w$, and no cancellation between $w$ and $u^{-1}$, where $w$ is *cyclically reduced*: it is a reduced word $a_0 a_1 \dots a_m$ such that $a_0 a_m \not = e$.

Now consider powers of the word: $a^n = u w^n u^{-1}$.

There is no cancellation between $u$ and $w^n$; and there is no cancellation between $w^n$ and $u^{-1}$; and there is no cancellation within $w^n$ because we defined $w$ to be cyclically reduced. So $a^n$ is not the identity word, because its length is not $0$.

Comment: So I get $w^n=1$, but then how do I claim $w \in [a]$?

Comment: How can $w^n = 1$ when $w$ is cyclically reduced? There is no cancellation between $a_m$ and $a_0$.

Comment: $w^n=(uau^-1)(uau^-1)...(uau^-1)=u(a^n)u^-1=uu^-1=1$

Comment: I'm suggesting that you throw out the supposition that $a$ be torsion, and just prove the theorem directly.

Comment: Can you spell it out more? I am really stuck.

Comment: Suppose for example that $w = ab^2ab^{-1}a^{-1}$. Then writing $u = ab$ and $v=ba$, we have $w = uvu^{-1}$ and $w^n = uv^nu^{-1} = ab(ba)^nb^{-1}a^{-1}$, which is manifestly not the empty word. You can write any word $w$ as $uvu^{-1}$ in this manner with $v$ cyclically reduced, and then $w^n = uv^nu^{-1}$,which not the empty word.

Comment: Why do we get to assume an arbitrary element can be writes as $uwu^{-1}$ with w cyclically reduced?

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom If it's not already cyclically reduced, then pull the first letter out into $u$ and the last letter out into $u^{-1}$. Repeat if necessary until $w$ is cyclically reduced.