# Let $F$ be a free group, $H \leq F$ and $[F:H]=n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that whenever $K \leq F$ then we have $K \cap H \neq 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

Let $F$ be a free group, $H \leq F$ and $[F:H]=n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that whenever $K \leq F$ then we have $K \cap H \neq 1$

I'm trying to figure out why this is, I'm having trouble, if somebody could walk me through a proof that would be great. Also, what are the different ways of understanding that every nontrivial element of a free group has infinite order? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If $x\in F$ had order $n$, then $x^n=e$, and $F$ isn't free.

Comment: If you are having trouble with elements having infinite order part you can see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2217221/29123) if you are viewing free groups through the reduced word perspective.

Comment: Did you leave something out? What if $K=\{1\}$?

Answer (score -1):

Let $x\neq 1\in K$.

Then $x^m\in H$ for some $m\le n $
(because there are only $n$ $H$-cosets).

So $x^m\in H\cap K$.

So $x^m=1$.

So $x$ has finite order in $F$.

Comment: How do we know that $K\ne\{1\}$?

Comment: Yes, that would be an exception.   @bof

Comment: I'm thinking we can just consider left cosets.  @runway44

Comment: There are only $n$ left (or right) cosets.  With that we should be able to get $x^m\in H$ for some $m\le n$.  @runway44

Comment: Technically I might need to correct that.  @runway44